# How can I concatenate the array content with its index value

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, concatenation

I want to concatenate the index value of array with its content and then save it in a new array.For example I have the array of distances `arr[]={"1.3","1.5","4.6"}`

I want to concatenate these distance values with their index values and store it in new array..
I want my new Array be like: `new[]= {"1.3:0","1.5:1","4.6:2"}`
is it possible and if yes then please tell how.. i have searched the google and find this function

```
var s = String.Join("; ",data.Split(',')
              .Select((d, i) => d.Trim() + "= " + i.ToString())
              .ToArray());
```

but this function is for string and my array also don't have any comma for split function.
what can be the solution for it ?

Comment: Why not just use a for loop?

Answer (score 5):

The `Split` is to form the `string[]` from a `string`. If you already have the `string[]` then all you need is:

```
var result = yourArray.Select((item,index) => $"{item}:{index}").ToArray();
```

*See that the `$` is C#6.0 String Interpolation. If you want instead you can just use simple string concatenations or `string.Format` instead*